# PanHandler doesn't detect touch events inside Modal

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have added a `PanHandler` to check if my app goes idle, and when it does, it shows a warning. The PanHandler works for all the content inside the page, but not when a `Modal` is shown. The touch events inside the modal seems to be ignored. The code is as follows.

```
render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.mainContainer}
                  collapsable={false}
                  {...this.pagePanResponder.panHandlers}>
                {this.addModal()}
                //Content
            </View>
);

addModal() {
        return (
            <Modal
                animationType="fade"
                transparent={true}
                visible={this.state.addModalVisible}>
                //Content
            </Modal>
        )
}

pageLastInteraction = new Date();
pagePanResponder = {};

componentWillMount() {
        this.panResponderSetup();
}

panResponderSetup() {
        this.pagePanResponder = PanResponder.create({
            onStartShouldSetPanResponder: this.handleStartShouldSetPanResponder,
            onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: this.handleMoveShouldSetPanResponder,
            onResponderTerminationRequest: () => false,
            onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture: () => false,
            onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: () => false,
            onPanResponderTerminationRequest: () => true,
            onShouldBlockNativeResponder: () => false,
        });

        this._maybeStartWatchingForInactivity();
}

_maybeStartWatchingForInactivity = () => {
        if (this._inactivityTimer) {
            return;
        }

        this._inactivityTimer = setInterval(() => {
            if (
                new Date() - this.pageLastInteraction >= TIME_TO_WAIT_FOR_INACTIVITY_MS
            ) {
                this._setIsInactive();
            }
        }, INACTIVITY_CHECK_INTERVAL_MS);
};

_setIsActive = () => {
        this.pageLastInteraction = new Date();
        if (this.state.timeWentInactive) {
            this.setState({ timeWentInactive: null, isIdle: false });
        }
        this._maybeStartWatchingForInactivity();
};

_setIsInactive = () => {
        console.log("PAGE WENT IDLE");
        if (this.idleWarningModal != null) {
            this.setState({
                addModalVisible: false
            }, () => {
                this.idleWarningModal.showModal();
            });
        }
        this.setState({ timeWentInactive: new Date(), isIdle: true });
        clearInterval(this._inactivityTimer);
        this._inactivityTimer = null;
};

handleStartShouldSetPanResponder = () => {
        this._setIsActive();
        return false;
};

handleMoveShouldSetPanResponder = () => {
        this._setIsActive();
        return false;
};
```

All the events in the main view seems to get covered by the PanHandler, except the content in the Modal. How to add the PanHandler to the Modal as well?

React Native Version - 0.55.4
React Version - 16.3.1

Answer (score 0):

Well, stupid mistake.

```
onResponderTerminationRequest: () => this.handleMoveShouldSetPanResponder
```

This fixed the issue. As `onPress` events were ignored by my logic before.